# MikTex 22.8 Missing XeLaTex Command to be used with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, latex, xelatex

I have been using XeLaTex in a MATLAB in a code that I originally wrote 7 years ago in MATLAB. After my latest update to MikTex 22.8 the code no longer works and it generates an empty PDF file.

The command that I used to use is the following

```
xelatex --quiet --include-directory="D:\Documents\XXX" --output-directory="C:\Users\XXX\Desktop" --aux-directory="D:\Documents\XXX" "D:\Documents\XXX/main.tex"
```

Looking at the bin directory of the new installation I could not find the xelatex command. The only alternative was miktex-xetex so I changed the command to the following

```
miktex-xetex --quiet --include-directory="D:\Documents\XXX" --output-directory="C:\Users\XXX\Desktop" --aux-directory="D:\Documents\XXX" "D:\Documents\XXX/main.tex"
```

but this throws an error and does not recognize article documentclass.

How can I create my PDFs using MikTex-XeTex?